# Material that reflects only a certain polarization?

Tags: material-science, optical-materials

Do materials exist that (significantly) reflect one polarisation of light and transmit all others?

Comment: Depending on the application that you have in mind Brewster's Angle may be of interest to you. If, however, you are interested in a more general behavior then I have no suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reflect on polarization and transmit all others'? In linearly polarized light, if you reflect one, there is only one other polarization to consider.

Comment: Such materials can be constructed, and are used to create modern [polarizing beam splitters](https://marketplace.idexop.com/store/SupportDocuments/TN_HTB_Beamsplitter.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every material. Well, at a certain angle, at least (the [Brewster angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster's_angle)), where p-polarized light is not reflected and hence only s-polarized light is reflected.

There is a modern interest in optical metamaterials and such things to engineer polarization reflections over wider angle ranges, though they tend to be limited in frequency.